# Can Not update scene from another controller in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to `Javafx`, I have a `menuBar` and multiple scenes that I can switch between them using the `MenuBar`, all worked fine until I tried to do something when clicking the menu item other than showing the scene.

I'm trying to show some writing in the textfield `nom` by using the method `reload();` of the scene that I'm trying to show, I call the `Enfantcontroller` from my `homeController` class where I have the menu items action methods and I call the `reload()` to write the text to the textfield in `enfantView` method when I click the menu item  but nothing happens after I load the controller for that scene. here's my code:

**EnfantController class**

```
    public class EnfantController implements Initializable {  

        @FXML
        private TextField nom;


        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO

        }
        public void reload() {
               this.nom.setText("vndghj");    
        }

}
```

**homeController class**

```
public class CrechHomeController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    private AnchorPane enfant;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            // TODO
            enfant = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(("/Views/Enfant.fxml")));


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CrechHomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    public void enfantItemAction() throws IOException {
        // getting the controller class and execute the reload method

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Views/Enfant.fxml"));
        loader.load();

        EnfantController enfantController = loader.getController();
        enfantController.reload();
        borderPane.setCenter(enfant);

    }
}
```

I know I might be overlooking something here, but I can't figure out what it is, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the fxml in the `initialize` method.

In the `enfantItemAction` you load the fxml again and use the controller created, but you show the node created in the `initialize` method instead.

You need to use the controller created when the fxml you show was loaded, e.g.

```
@FXML
public void enfantItemAction() throws IOException {
    // getting the controller class and execute the reload method

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Views/Enfant.fxml"));
    Node node = loader.load();

    EnfantController enfantController = loader.getController();
    enfantController.reload();
    borderPane.setCenter(node);
}
```

Alternatively you could also store the controller created when loading the fxml file in the `initialize` method in a field and not load the fxml again in the `enfantItemAction` method.